# Change vuetify simple-table to data-table

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have this simple table in Vuetify, without headers and only one column. How can I change it to vuetify `v-data-table`?

```
  <v-simple-table>
    <thead />
    <tbody>
      <tr
        v-for="item in categories"
        :key="item"
        @click="handleClick"
      >
        <td>{{ item }}</td>
        <v-switch />
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </v-simple-table>
```

`categories` is a simple array of strings. I want to change it to data-table in order to nicely handle clicking and selecting rows.

Comment: I added an answer. Hope that will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this codesandbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-71617004-simple-to-v-data-table-bm2yn1?file=/src/components/Example.vue

### Using body slot

You can use the `body` slot of the data table and use almost the same code you have in your simple table like this. This way you set up the handleClick function in the `tr`:

```html
<v-data-table
   :headers="headers"
   :items="items"
   hide-default-footer
   hide-default-header               
   :items-per-page="-1"
   :footer-props="{
      itemsPerPageOptions: [-1],
   }"
>
   <template v-slot:body="{ items}">
      <tbody>
         <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item"  @click="handleClick(item)">
               <td align="left">{{item}}</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </template>
</v-data-table>
```

### Using item slot

Or you can use the `item` slot, like this. In this other way, the handleClick function is configured using the `@click:row` event of the data table.

If you try to use the `item` slot with your array of strings, it will work but you'll get some warnings in your console. Telling you that your data-table item slot expected an object and received an string. That's because `v-data-table` component expects to receive an array of objects.

To avoid this warning you can simply convert your array of string into a dummy array of objects using Array.prototype.map, and bind the computed property instead.

```js
computed: {
   myItemsTransformed() {
      return this.items.map(item => ({ name: item }));
   }
},
```

```html
<v-data-table
   :headers="headers"
   :items="myItemsTransformed"
   hide-default-footer
   hide-default-header               
   :items-per-page="-1"
   :footer-props="{
      itemsPerPageOptions: [-1],
   }"               
   @click:row="(item) => handleClick(item.name)"
>
   <template #item.name="{ item }">
      {{ item.name }}
   </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Notice that in both examples I have used the props `hide-default-footer`, `hide-default-header` to hide the footer and header of the data table and also set the `items-per-page` to `-1`. To show all the items of the table and avoid the pagination.

Comment: Thank you for the different methods and explanations. However, I have an issue with both of the approaches. With the first approach I get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'select')` when I try to select a row with `row.select(true)`. Second approach selects all the rows when I click on one. When I print the value, it actually only prints the item from the selected row but the color for all rows get changed, as if they are currently selected.

Comment: Yeah, on the first approach it will require a bit more of code to be able to handle row selection since in that case we have a custom body for the data table. For the second approach, I think you might be missing the `item-key` prop, that's the value that will be stored in the selected array of items, if you don't specify that all rows gets selected. Do you want to show the checkboxes? Also, are you selecting the row with the handleClick function?

Comment: I have updated both approaches to handle row selection, check the codesandbox again. Since we started working with items selection I had to use the dummy array in both examples. Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Yes, `item-key` did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can change like this **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    categoryList: ['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3'],
  }),
  computed: {
    categoriesHeader() {
      return [
        { text: "Name", value: "name" }
      ];
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.5.0/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="a">
    <v-data-table :headers="categoriesHeader" :items="categoryList" item-key="id" class="elevation-1">
      <template v-slot:[`item.name`]="{ item }">
        {{ item }}
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: I have accepted the answer. I have a small question, what does using the nested `<template>` mean? What I have is a component which has all the stuffs already inside `<template>`, with your solution there is one more. I just want to know its significance, thank you :)

Comment: by using `<template>` along with `v-slot` basically we are creating our own table rows and cells.

Comment: Some vuetify components comes with special sections for easier customization called `slots`, in this case Rohit is using the item slot of the data table that let him customize individual colums content. In this case `item.name`. Looks like, he's missing the handleClick function you set in your simple table. Let me show you another way to achieve this as well.

Comment: I have small issue with this, when I select a row with `row.select(true)` inside onClick function, all the rows get selected. I only want one row to be selected so that I can change the color of it.